# Forward slashing transforming into \/ when passed through JSONObject in Android

Tags: android, json

I have a string that is being put into a JSONObject. It looks like this before it is passed:

```
  Before: /storage/sdcard/Download/signature-1383757302516.jpg

  After: \/storage\/sdcard\/Download\/signature-1383757302516.jpg
```

Here is what my code looks like:

```
   // make JSON object to hold the information, which is sent to the server
  JSONObject jsonObjSend = new JSONObject();
  jsonObjSend.put("signature", signatureFile.getAbsolutePath())
```

The output for jsonObjSend().toString() is:

```
  \/storage\/sdcard\/Download\/signature-1383757302516.jpg
```

Is JSONOBject encoding the information? How do I prevent it from modifying the forward slash?

*EDIT: 
I solved it using regex to remove the escape characters.

```
  jsonObjSend.toString().replaceAll("\\\\/", "/")
```

Comment: the output ought to be something like `{"signature","\/storage\/sdcard\/Download\/signature-1383757302516.jpg"}`   in which case the extra slashes ("\") are ESCAPING your "/".

Answer (score 0):

`toString()` method usually returns value with escape characters when it is called on a complex object. Your value is stored just fine. Try to call

```
jsonObjSend.get("signature");
```

Comment: I am using log.i("tag", jsonObjectSend.get("signature").toString()) but the output is still showing  \/storage\/sdcard\/Download\/signature-1383757302516.jpg

Comment: what about `jsonObjectSend.getString("signature")` ?

Comment: jsonObjectSend.getString("signature") produces the same result